# Debug.WriteLine equivalent in MonoTouch/MonoDroid?

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

What's the equivalent to Debug.WriteLine for MonoTouch or MonoDroid?

Here's a guide for MonoDroid:
http://monodroid.net/Documentation/Guides/Android_Debug_Log

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For MonoTouch, Console.WriteLine will show up in MonoDevelop and in the logs from your iOS device.

For MonoDroid, you can use the Android.Util.Log class to log debug, info, errors etc that you can view from the Android Debug Bridge's logcat (adb logcat).  An example would be something like this to log an info message : Android.Util.Log.Info("Barcode", "Scan button pressed.")

Answer (score 6):

Mono for Android provides [Debug.WriteLine()](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aSystem.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(System.String%2cSystem.Object%5b%5d)), as does MonoTouch, so I'm not sure why you need a workaround.

`Debug.WriteLine()` is visible within MonoDevelop (when debugging) and is also copied to the Android Debug Log with the `mono-stdout` tag. `System.Console` output is also copied to the Android Debug Log with the `mono-stdout` (`Console.Out`) and `mono-stderr` (`Console.Error`) tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Console.WriteLine with both Monotouch and Monodroid for debug output.